# Adding component to window

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, components

GraphicsWindow Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
public class GraphicsWindow extends BlankWindow
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        this.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    }
}
```

BlankWindow Class (main):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Container;
public class BlankWindow extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Picture");
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(400,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        GraphicsWindow component = new GraphicsWindow();
        frame.add(pane);
        pane.add(component);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on the pane.add(component); whenever I try to run it.

Comment: The `GraphicsWindow` should extends `JPanel` instead of `BlankWindow`

Comment: You're adding a JFrame to a JFrame -- you can't do that, and you're trying to draw in a JFrame's paintComponent method, a method that this class doesn't have. Most importantly, all your code is nothing but guess work, and that won't work. Read the Swing graphics tutorials so you won't have to guess. Please check [this Swing info link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) for more.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GraphicsWindow`, you must extend `javax.swing.JComponent` not `BlankWindow`

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html